# Is there any good way to proxying library's network callls?

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

For example, I import some library, that uses **requests** module for getting something from Internet. And it doesn't have any way to set proxy. How I can set proxy for this module more cleaner way?

I found, that it can be done by setting global proxy - `os.environ["all_proxy"] = "http://proxy:port`, but that way seems to me dirty, I don't like setting it global.

How you solve this in your projects?

Comment: https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, I can use it for my requests calls, but answer is about some third-party library. I can't set proxy for its calls (except global setting)